# In Intellij IDEA, how to change "messages: Build" fonts ?

Tags: intellij-idea, fonts

I would like to use a monospaced, small font in Intellij IDEA "messages: build" tooltip windows.

I discovered that I can override it in "Appearence & Behavior > Appearence: Override default font". But it change it everywhere, including in the setting menu, title, etc.

I tested in "Editor > Color Scheme > Console Font": "Use console font in place of default", but it only changes in some others console windows, not "message: build".

Does anybody know how to do that? I use Community edition 2018.1.4.

(ps: the reason is that my compiler prints statistics which get all ill-aligned with the default messages non monospaced font).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The font used in Messages tool window is indeed taken from Appearence & Behavior > Appearence settings. There is a related request: [IDEA-125896](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-125896) to be able to configure it separately from the appearance theme.